# aiohttp: how to add sub_app to sub_app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I need to add sub_app to sub_app. Here is my code

```
app = web.Application()

subapp = web.Application()
subapp.router.add_get('/page1/', handler)
app.add_subapp('/wt/', subapp)

subsubapp = web.Application()
subsubapp.router.add_get('/page2/', handler)
subapp.add_subapp('/sub/', subsubapp)
```

Why the page `/wt/sub/page2/` is not found?
I think that the path for `subsubapp` is a concatenation of `/wt/` (`sub_app`) and `/sub/` (`subsubapp`). Am I wrong? What is the rule?

Regards,
Valery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aiohttp` version 2.3 has a subtle bug: it doesn't inform about improper sub application initialization order.

Sub-application logically is **frozen** after registering in parent, adding new routes to it is an error.

Not released yet aiohttp 3.0 raises explicit exception on `app.add_subapp()` call, see corresponding [issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2656) and [pull request](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/2657) for more details.

To fix your snippet reorder route registering calls:

```
from aiohttp import web

async def handler(request):
    return web.Response(text="OK")

subsubapp = web.Application()
subsubapp.router.add_get('/page2/', handler)

subapp = web.Application()
subapp.router.add_get('/page1/', handler)
subapp.add_subapp('/sub/', subsubapp)

app = web.Application()
app.add_subapp('/wt/', subapp)

web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

After this fetching `http://127.0.0.1:8080/wt/sub/page2/` resources returns `200 OK`.